# Was the speed trim system on the B737 Classic modified to counter increased thrust?

Tags: jet-engine, boeing-737

How much additional thrust did the 737 classic generate compared to the original 737? Was the speed trim system added to counter the additional thrust?

Comment: [Wiki says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737#Specifications) the 1st generation 737s had between 62 and 73 kN of thrust per engine and the 2nd generation ("Classic") between 89 and 105 kN per engine.

Comment: Related: [When was the Speed Trim System implemented on the Boeing 737?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65258/when-was-the-speed-trim-system-implemented-on-the-boeing-737)