# Do the trim wheels on the Boeing 737NG move by themselves during the takeoff roll?

Tags: takeoff, boeing-737, trim, horizontal-stabilizer

After the stab trim is set before take off, will it **move** by itself during the take off roll? If yes, why? Where can I find the reference?

Answer (score 3):

**The stab trim should not move by itself during the takeoff roll on the 737 NG.**

The stabilizer can in principle be moved by the following things:

- the stab trim switches on the control wheels: these are available during the takeoff roll, but do not operate automatically
- the autopilot trim: the autopilot is turned off during the takeoff roll, so no trim inputs are made here
- stabilizer trim wheels: these are mechanically linked and allow manual adjustment of the stabilizer, but no automatic operation
- the Speed Trim System (STS): the STS starts to be active 10s after takeoff, so not during the takeoff roll

The details are described in the Flight Crew Operating Manual (FCOM):

> **Stabilizer**
>
> The horizontal stabilizer is positioned by a single electric trim motor controlled
> through either the stab trim switches on the control wheel or autopilot trim. The
> stabilizer may also be positioned by manually rotating the stabilizer trim wheel.
>
> **Stabilizer Trim**
>
> Stabilizer trim switches on each control wheel actuate the electric trim motor
> through the main electric stabilizer trim circuit when the airplane is flown
> manually. With the autopilot engaged, stabilizer trim is accomplished through the
> autopilot stabilizer trim circuit. [...]
>
> **Speed Trim System**
>
> The speed trim system (STS) is a speed stability augmentation system designed to
> improve flight characteristics during operations with a low gross weight, aft center
> of gravity and high thrust when the autopilot is not engaged. [...]
> Conditions for speed trim operation are listed below:
>
> - Airspeed between 100 KIAS and Mach 0.5
> - 10 seconds after takeoff
> - 5 seconds following release of trim switches
> - Autopilot not engaged
> - Sensing of trim requirement

<sup>(Boeing 737NG FCOMv2 - 9.20.8 - Flight Controls, System Description)</sup>

Related:

- [When was the Speed Trim System implemented on the Boeing 737?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65258/when-was-the-speed-trim-system-implemented-on-the-boeing-737)
- [Was the speed trim system on the B737 Classic modified to counter increased thrust?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/69789/was-the-speed-trim-system-on-the-b737-classic-modified-to-counter-increased-thru)